# iOS UITextField Frame not committing

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield

I'm having an odd issue with updating my UI. In the code below, I've written comments blocking off what I am referring to as "Section 1" and "Section 2". No matter what, Section 1 works flawlessly and it commits the animation, but if I have section 1 in the code, section 2 does NOT work. The frame is set, but the animation is never carried out and it stays stationary

When I have both sections it does this:
http://cl.ly/image/2p3H0x3n3W1F/Screenshot%202014.02.10%2014.07.54.png
(Notice how the textfields below the stepper doesn't move)

When I have just section 2 it does this:
http://cl.ly/image/2H0C1p2M1M37/Screenshot%202014.02.10%2014.07.32.png
(The stepper moves correctly, but since section 1 doesn't exist it isn't creating the intermediary textfields)

Things I have already checked:

1. Ensuring I'm on the main thread (I am)
2. Checking all my outlets and ensuring that none of the variables aren't nil (They aren't)

I've noticed that the endAddressTextfield.frame does NOT show the changes in the completion block, but does in the animations block. So during the animation block, it's correct, in the completion block, it is still at its old position

[Animation block]

```
2014-02-10 14:15:38.253 traffic[1163:60b] animatedBegin frame: {{20, 20}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.253 traffic[1163:60b] animatedMid frame: {{20, 95}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.254 traffic[1163:60b] animatedMid frame: {{20, 140}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.254 traffic[1163:60b] animatedEnd frame: {{20, 185}, {280, 30}}
```

[Completion block]

```
2014-02-10 14:15:38.508 traffic[1163:60b] Begin frame: {{20, 20}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.509 traffic[1163:60b] Mid frame: {{20, 95}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.511 traffic[1163:60b] Mid frame: {{20, 140}, {280, 30}}
2014-02-10 14:15:38.512 traffic[1163:60b] End frame: {{20, 95}, {280, 30}}
```

The goal is to get the endAddressTextfield to move below the waypoints.

.h

```
@interface CreateCustomRouteViewController : UIViewController{

    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *startAddressTextfield;
    NSMutableArray* waypointTextfields;
    __weak IBOutlet UIStepper *waypointStepper;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *endAddressTextfield;
}
- (IBAction)waypointStepperValueChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CreateCustomRouteViewController.h"

@interface CreateCustomRouteViewController ()

@end

@implementation CreateCustomRouteViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    waypointTextfields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)waypointStepperValueChanged:(UIStepper*)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        CGRect frame;
        //beginSection1
        if ([waypointTextfields count] > sender.value){
            [[waypointTextfields lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
            [waypointTextfields removeLastObject];
        }else{
            frame = startAddressTextfield.frame;
            frame.origin.y = 50.0f + (sender.value) * 45.0f;
            UITextField* tmp = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            tmp.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            tmp.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            tmp.alpha = 0.25f;
            [self.view addSubview:tmp];
            [waypointTextfields addObject:tmp];
        }
        //endSection1

        //startSection2
        frame = endAddressTextfield.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 95.0f + (sender.value) * 45.0f;
        endAddressTextfield.frame = frame;
        //endSection2 
    }];
}

@end
```

Storyboard:

http://cl.ly/image/3d3f2M2d370g/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-10%20at%202.02.46%20PM.png

Outlets:

http://cl.ly/image/0U2M2f202B3S/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-10%20at%202.11.44%20PM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUTO LAYOUT WAS THE ISSUE. SIGH.